# Web Automation using Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I tried to automate some logins and copy paste from the web onto my own machine. When I try the same thing from company's intranet I face problems. My error message is:

> Object variable or With block variable not set.

Here is my code:

```
Sub getdata()
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim naziv, test, test2 As Variant

'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://example.com/Pages/default.aspx"

Do While IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set test = Doc
Set test2 = Doc

test2 = test.getElementById("testid")

MsgBox (test2.innerText)

End Sub
```

Comment: You have not initialized your Doc variable.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following two lines

```
Set test = Doc
Set test2 = Doc
```

Set the doc variable first

```
Set Doc = IE.document
```

and then set the test2 object

```
set test2 = Doc.getElementById("testid")
```

Comment: '--> `Set test2 = Doc.getElementById("testid")` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the correction. I forgot to add that. :)

Comment: ++ no worries, I also miss small things sometime :)

Comment: Thanks once again. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help, now I am getting another error message: Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed. I cannot imagine how can I solve that, I am trying it 1 week ago...thank you if you cam add some concerns :).